INA260 Module resolution
Is there any way to improve the resolution of INA260 module to uA and uV? It's an amp and volt meter with a resolution of 1mA 1mV
Datasheet:
https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/INA260

What do you mean by uA and uV? As in a resolution of 1uA/1uV, or in the single digits of uA/uV, or in the hundreds, etc...?

1uA/uV or 10uA/uV resolution

Related, if not identical: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/727312/measuring-micro-ampsua-and-micro-volts-uv

If you want to increase the resolution by 1000 or about 10 bits, then you would need a 26 bit A/D converter. This degree of performance is available in  the best DMMs which have resolutions of 7-1/2 and even 8-1/2 digits but are expensive. Do you really need that kind of performance since few sources have enough stability to justify such resolution.

Where should I add this AD converter? Yes I need this. This is a problem in one of my projects

Can you explain why you need 26 bits of dynamic range and why you can't use range-switching like everyone else?

In my project, I need to calculate the voltage and current and then find the power consumption simultaneously and automatically. Everything is done by an automated electronic system which is controlled by a microcontroller (ARM STM). So auto range dmm has nothing to do in my specific project. Note that the current could be 100uA or 1239uA, or 52390uA etc when the system is working. I was thinking if there is any solution to this???
